# Team Foundation Explorer plug-in

Tags: plugins, explorer, foundation

I am using Team Foundation Explorer plug-in for Eclipse on OSX. Is there a way to get a view like the one that Visual Studio shows you in Eclipse?

For example:

[image]

Comment: Here is the view I am looking for. http://creativescientist.com/VISUAL.JPG

Answer (score 0):

inside the team explorer view,you choose Home-> Source control explorer